# In Jmeter 2.13, How to make Non-HTML resource errors as warnings?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In My Application, for some of the images and js requests I am getting resource not found messages, same we informed developers to fix. Meanwhile they are going to fix that i just want to mark them as warnings instead of error and have to go ahead with execution to found out other unknown issues.
Can anyone please help me how to mark non-html resource errors as warnings in jmeter (I don’t want to exclude those from execution)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.
Edit user.properties and add:

> httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true